# How can I get my Kodak printer to default to A4 paper?

Tags: printing, paper

My Kodak Hero 5.1 all in one printer on a Windows 7 system always defaults in it's own settings to printing on Letter sized paper.  This is usually not a problem, however does come into play when attempting to print borderless documents.

When I go to printer preferences by right clicking on the printer in control panel, under the option for everyday printing I *can* change from Letter to A4, however once I move off the page after clicking apply it reverts to Letter size.

[image: Kodak Printer Preferences Panel]

Clicking the save button saves a new preset but then there is no way to put this as the default.

Has anyone managed to get this to stick or found a good alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hidden away in the printer properties:

1. Open **Devices & Printers** from the start menu
2. Right click on your printer and click **printer properties**
3. Go to the **advanced** tab
4. Click **Printing Defaults** on the bottom left corner
5. Set your chosen defaults and press OK on both windows

This is the only way that I have found to make defaults persist on my Kodak Hero.